# image processing with python

Tags: image, python-2.7, image-processing

I have this input`image1` which is 20x20 size and looks like this

```
00000000000000000000
00111000000000000000
01101100000001111000
11000110000001111110
11100000001100011110
```

and I need a function that will generate an output, say `image2` of 20x20 size, that will look like this

```
00000000000000000000
00111000000000000000
11011000000022220000
11000110000002222220
11000110000002222220
11100000003300022220
```

The difference is that the first appears to be a grey-scale image (only 0 and 1) while the desired output, based on the similar areas of the input image, will now contain 2,3 and so on.

So far I am looking for some  of `pillow`'s build in functions that might suit me but I am not even sure if I am looking in the right direction. Could you please suggest a way to approach this?

Comment: You should have a look to Flood-Fill-Algorithms they are easy and fast to implement.

Comment: @PeterNL I had no clue.. Alright thanks

Answer (score 1):

Did you checked this previous post on stackoverflow ([Simple object recognition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449139/simple-object-recognition)) ?

In sum you can use SciPy's ndimage.label()
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.measurements.label.html#scipy.ndimage.measurements.label

Good luck.

Comment: `ndimage.label()` is the way to go.  It essentially performs flood fill.  Good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well I would suggest to write a simple function

STEPS :

1. make a copy of the image filled with zeros and use it as the visited array
2. perform dfs. You just have to find islands on the image it is a simple graph problem. google for finding islands in a graph.

Hope it helps and you always dont need a named algo to do simple things